# creating new java entity class (Java SE 1.7)

Tags: java, netbeans, annotations, entity

So i'm trying to create a simple entity class called student. According to the tutorial, I'd need `@Entity` annotation for this class but when I put that in, NetBeans (7) keeps complaining that the symbol was not found.
Any idea?

Oh and my class looks like this

```
@Entity
public class Student
{
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not a part of the standard Java API, it's from the Java Enterprise specifications.  On your project's 'Libraries' right click, add Library, and add 'Java EE 6 API Library' or just 'Persistence'

Comment: i tried that but the @Entity annotation still gets underlined.
Am I missing something?

Comment: did you clean and build after changing the libraries?

Comment: never mind! it was my fault! i forgot to include the javax.persistence package! thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: netbeans quick-tip: ctrl+shift+i  :)